# What creature does this skeleton belong to?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Towards the beginning of *A New Hope* when C-3PO and R2-D2 are on Tatoonie and after they go their own ways, just before 3PO is picked up by the Jawas he's standing in front of a giant skeleton.

### What creature does this skeleton belong to?

[image]

[image]